# Hook to WM6 sound

Tags: windows-mobile, audio, hook

How can I hook into the window mobile sound (driver?) and read the data while it is passing data to the speaker?

Answer (score 0):

While creating a new wavedev audio driver might do what you want (it's not 100% clear how you want to acheive your goal) what you're probably after is the [Mixer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705739.aspx). You might take a look at [Andy Raffman's blog on audio mixer terminology](http://blogs.msdn.com/medmedia/archive/2007/01/12/what-do-you-mean-by-mixer.aspx) to see where your needs lie.

DirectSound used to be an option (4.2 and earlier) but was [removed in 5.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446919.aspx).